# how to retain radio button selected when i again view same view page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, radio-button

I have small doubts regarding radio buttons i.e I want that to preserve the selected radio button,that when I again open that view ,the radio button which I had selected should remain selected.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"mobileNumber"] length]>0){
        MobileNum.text=[defaults valueForKey:@"mobileNumber"];
    }
    else {
        MobileNum.text=@"";
    }
    if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"amount"] length]>0) {
        amount.text=[defaults valueForKey:@"amount"];
    }
    else {
        amount.text=@"";
    }

    if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"operator"] length]>0) {
        operatorLabel.text = [defaults valueForKey:@"operator"];
    }else{
        operatorLabel.text = @"Select Operator";
    }

    if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"circle"] length]>0) {
        circleLabel.text = [defaults valueForKey:@"circle"];
    }else{
        circleLabel.text = @"Select Circle";
    }

    if ([defaults valueForKey:@"credit card"]) {
        [criditRadio setSelected:YES];

    }else{
        [criditRadio setSelected:NO];
    }
    if ([defaults valueForKey:@"debit card"]) {
        debitRadio.selected=YES;
    }else{
        debitRadio.selected=NO;
    }
    if ([defaults valueForKey:@"net bank"]) {
        netRadio.selected=NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: your coding is fine, what the change u need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your coding is fine

```
if ([defaults valueForKey:@"credit card"]) {
    [criditRadio setSelected:YES];

}else{
    [criditRadio setSelected:NO];
}
if ([defaults valueForKey:@"debit card"]) {
    debitRadio.selected=YES;
}else{
    debitRadio.selected=NO;
}
if ([defaults valueForKey:@"net bank"]) {
    netRadio.selected=NO;
}
```

here u need to compare the `NSUserdefault Value` on every time to navigate this page and 
here I attached the sample project as per your need download this link of the [project](https://www.sendspace.com/file/bflyma)